# FB.api not working properly

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I am using facebook JavaScript sdk for login functionality.
But FB.api('/me', function(response)) not working as expected.
When i finished with click on login button it should display my profile information in the div(id=status)
but it does not show up that info for the first time, but when i refresh page it shows that. so i want it to display in div once i finished with login button click without having to refresh or reload the page.
below is the my script code:

```
    function statusChangeCallback(response) 
{
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);

    if (response.status === 'connected') 
    {
      testAPI();  
    } 
    else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') 
    {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +'into this app.';
    } 
    else 
    {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +'into Facebook.';
    }
}

function checkLoginState() 
{
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) 
    {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
}

window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
{
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'MY_APP_ID',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.2' // use version 2.2
  });

 FB.getLoginStatus(function(loginResponse) 
 {
    statusChangeCallback(loginResponse);
  });
};

function Logout()
{
    FB.logout(function(){document.location.reload();});
}
function getPhoto()
{
    FB.api('/me/picture?type=normal', function(response) 
    {
        var str="<br/><b>Pic</b> : <img src='"+response.data.url+"'/>";
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML+=str;
    }); 
}

var myWindow=null;
function fblogin()
{
   FB.login(function(response)
   {
    console.log('FB.login response',response);
    checkLoginState();
   });
   return false;
}


(function(d, s, id) 
{
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


function testAPI() 
{
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response)
    {   
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      var str="<b>Name</b> : "+response.name+"<br>";
      str +="<b>Link: </b>"+response.link+"<br>";
      str +="<b>Username:</b> "+response.username+"<br>";
      str +="<b>id: </b>"+response.id+"<br>";
      console.log(response);
      str +="<b>Email:</b> "+response.email+"<br>";
      str +="<input type='button' value='Get Photo' onclick='getPhoto();'/>";
      str +="<input type='button' value='Logout' onclick='Logout();'/>";
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =str;
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
}
```

so above snippet calls sometimes but not seamlessly.
Please help

Comment: without all your code including the login part it´s hard to help

Comment: @luschn ok i am giving all code

Comment: @luschn i added full code

Comment: actually i am able to login but not able to display info in div just after immediate login.

Comment: that´s some weird code...maybe this blogpost helps you: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: `FB.getLoginStatus` caches results, and likely that is your problem. After successful login (which you can check via the `FB.login` response), there is no need to call that method again – just make your API call directly.

Comment: @CBroe can you elaborate what i exactly needs to do ?

Comment: check out the blogpost and make sure you understand what each function is for and how it needs to be used.

Comment: @luschn i followed that blog post and implemented in same fashion but still no luck. It still does not displays information immediately. it still requires additional refresh.

Comment: in that case you should post a test link

Comment: Change:
function checkLoginState() 
{
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) 
    {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
}

To
function checkLoginState(response) 
{
      statusChangeCallback(response);
}

And tell us how that goes. I guess you can refactor this even more, but I would still try this for the sake of debugging.